# Use spaces in UltiSnips snippets

Tags: vim, ultisnips

I can't seem to use spaces in snippets at all. Ultisnips throws errors on the following:

```
snippet 'dv(?=[ \n])' "derivative" rA 2
\dv{$1}{$2}$0
endsnippet
```

My goal is to expand the snippet automatically if and only if `dv` precedes a space or newline, without removing the space or newline. Whenever I try to insert a space in any snippet, UltiSnips throws

```
UltiSnips.snippet.source.file.base.SnippetSyntaxError: Invalid multiword trigger: ''dv(?= )' "derivative" rA 2' in ~/.vim/UltiSnips/tex.snippets:23
```

So the issue seems to be that "multi-word triggers" aren't allowed. Is there a reason for this, and is there a workaround (that doesn't involve a negative lookahead for every character that isn't a space or newline)?

Answer (score -1):

me from yesterday.

The issue is that the priority was improperly placed, that is, the previous line should have 'priority 2'. This has nothing to do with being unable to use spaces in snippets.

Comment: care to share your fix?

Comment: I placed the priority at the end of the line, not as a statement before the snippet, and the latter is correct syntax.